Not able to have a theme file that can be used in all Sass files
The Goal
My goal is to have @use '@angular/material' as mat in theme.sass and import or use theme.sass in any other sass files.
The Problem
theme.sass:
@use '@angular/material' as mat

@include mat.core()
$localPalette: mat.$red-palette

So far, there are no errors and everything works fine, BUT if another sass file contains @use "../theme" as style or @import "../theme" or @use "@angular/material" as mat, I will get this error:

Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use '@angular/material' as mat
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  ..\theme.sass 1:1  @use
  colors.sass 1:1     root stylesheet
```

You may find this project on GitHub. Please see src/theme.sass and src/styles/colors.sass
I use the latest version of WebStorm with this Sass arguments:
--load-path ../node_modules $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css


Actually I tried your code there is no such problem. Only thing I did different was, is that I added colors.sass to the angular.json, the build ran without any issues
...
"styles": [
          "src/theme.sass",
          "src/styles/colors.sass"
],
...

I was able to get this error, only when I ran sass directly!
sass ./src/theme.sass theme.css


sass ./src/styles/colors.sass colors.css

Both these are not aware of the angular material code already present so you are getting this error, since sass will be configured in angular to look at node_modules and get the styles from node_modules. So as far as I can see there are no errors in your code!
Forked branch

Thanks for your answer! But what if I want to import theme.sass in any Angular components? I think it is not the best practice if I add all these sass files in angular.json.

@xRay But we will need to run it only once, you can create a separate file that contains all the variables you want to export and use, also only running through SASS i got this error, if I just import @use '@angular/material' as mat it wont give me any error during angular build!
